# {{#each ... }} on Mandrill is resulting in an empty string

Tags: json, handlebars.js, mandrill

I'm trying to create a Handlebars template in Mandrill that will print out a list of items. We're using the `{{#each}}` construct to do this:

```
{{#each bottles}}
    <p>{{this.bottle_title}}</p>
    <p>{{this.description}}</p>
    <p>{{this.price}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

And, we're passing in JSON like this:

```
{/*...*/
    'bottles' : [
        {
          "wine_id":"1599",
          "bottle_title":"2012 Sapphire Hill \u2018Ketchum Reserve\u2019 Pinot Noir",
          "description":"<p>\n <strong>Winemaker Notes:<\/strong><br \/>\n Blended from 4 clones, with 115 and 777 dominating to create this bold yet balanced wine. Aged for 20 months on French oak, this wine flaunts bright cherry, blackberry, and subtle vanilla with a very long finish.<br \/>\n &nbsp;<\/p>\n",
          "price":"50"
        },
        {
          "wine_id":"1600",
          "bottle_title":"2012 Sapphire Hill \u2018D\u2019Argento\u2019 Pinot Noir",
          "description":"<p>\n <strong>Winemaker Notes:<\/strong><br \/>\n D&#39;Argento (Silver) was crafted for our 25th Anniversary and uses 4 clones from the fabled Ketcham Estate in Russian River Valley....<\/p>\n",
          "price":"52"
       }
    ] /*...*/
}
```

I've verified that if I just print out `{{bottles}}` then I get the full JSON above outputted into the email. But `{{#each bottles}}{{this.bottles}}{{/each}}` doesn't print out anything nor does the example we tried above. Any ideas how we can get this working?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we considered that regular JSON was getting written to the email when we did `{{bottles}}` we realized we were double-encoding the JSON. Doh! So for anyone else who runs into this issue, be sure you're not making the same silly mistake :)