# Each-loop in mandrill using handlebars and Mandrill-dotnet -library

Tags: c#, json, templates, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill to send emails, and are using Handlebars to render content in the email.

If I add variables like this everything works fine:

Backend:

```
message.AddRecipientVariable("test@gmail.com", "MYVALUE", "some value");
```

Html-Template:

```
<p>{{MYVALUE}}</p>
```

But if I try to use {{#each}} - the each section in the sent email is empty. What am I doing wrong here. Do I pass the `objStringArray` the wrong way or is there somthing else missing out to render the loop?

Backend:

```
var objList = new List<MyObj> {new MyObj() {Qty = "125"}, new MyObj() { Qty = "16"}};

var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var objStringArray = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(objList.ToArray());

message.AddRecipientVariable("test@gmail.com", "VALUES", objStringArray);

message.merge_language = "handlebars";
_mandrillApi.SendMessage(message, templateName, new List<TemplateContent>());
```

Html-Template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each VALUES}}
    <li>{{Qty}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

[Handlebars in mandrill](http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html#loops)

[Mandrill-dotnet](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the library I'm using ([Mandrill-DotNet](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/master/src/Mandrill/Models/EmailMessage.cs)) the method: `AddRecipientVariable()` only takes type string as the content variable. And the madrill-API wants a list when doing the {{#each}} -thing. So by changing the library source code a bit, I can pass in a regular `List<dynamic>()` to `AddRecipientVariable`-s content-parameter instead, and it works perfect.

By changing source-code:

```
public struct merge_var
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    ///     The content.
    /// </summary>
    public string content;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The name.
    /// </summary>
    public string name;

    #endregion
}

    public void AddRecipientVariable(string recipient, string name, string content)
    {
        if (this.merge_vars == null)
        {
            this.merge_vars = new List<rcpt_merge_var>();
        }

        rcpt_merge_var entry = this.merge_vars.Where(e => e.rcpt == recipient).FirstOrDefault();
        if (entry == null)
        {
            entry = new rcpt_merge_var { rcpt = recipient };
            this.merge_vars.Add(entry);
        }

        var mv = new merge_var { name = name, content = content };

        entry.vars.Add(mv);
    }
```

To this (`string content` to `dynamic content`) :

```
public struct merge_var
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    ///     The content.
    /// </summary>
    public dynamic content;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The name.
    /// </summary>
    public string name;

    #endregion
}

    public void AddRecipientVariable(string recipient, string name, dynamic content)
    {
        if (this.merge_vars == null)
        {
            this.merge_vars = new List<rcpt_merge_var>();
        }

        rcpt_merge_var entry = this.merge_vars.Where(e => e.rcpt == recipient).FirstOrDefault();
        if (entry == null)
        {
            entry = new rcpt_merge_var { rcpt = recipient };
            this.merge_vars.Add(entry);
        }

        var mv = new merge_var { name = name, content = content };

        entry.vars.Add(mv);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Djrill in Python, so I a not familiar with the library you are using.

But you should make sure your JSON is not nested in a wrong way as mentioned in [{{#each ... }} on Mandrill is resulting in an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705984/each-on-mandrill-is-resulting-in-an-empty-string)